# Which pepper is typically part of salt and pepper?

Tags: pepper

When people add salt and pepper to say chips, which pepper is it typically?

I had chicken and chips recently with pepper and it was black colour bits, would it have been black pepper?

Comment: If the black bits were pepper, it was probably black pepper. Are you sure the black bits were pepper and not something else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is typically black pepper.  The two common black varieties are Tellicherry and Malabar.  The peppercorn is the fruit of a flowering vine that is harvested when it is red, and ripe.  Each fruit contains one seed, which is dried and then packaged whole or ground.

Comment: Occasionally white pepper gets used. Almost never the red ones.

Comment: No, the peppercorn is the dried fruit. It's a drupe fruit (aka "stone fruit"), which contains a single seed in its centre.